# How to find the probabilities?

Tags: probability

Boolean random variables $a,b,c,$ and $d$ are all independent of each other. P(a) = 0.22, P(b) = 0.47, P(c)= 0.82, and P(d) = 0.59. Given this, find the following probabilities.

(i) $P(a \land b \land \lnot c \land d~=~1)$

(ii) $P(a \land \lnot d~=~1) $

(iii) $P(a \to b~=~1)$

(iv) $P(\lnot a \to \lnot b~=~1)$

(v) $P((a \lor \lnot c) \to (b \land d)~=~1)$

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I dont know that's why Im asking..guide me to right direction

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of an intersection of *mutually independent* events is the product of the probabilities of those events.  Sometimes called the "product rule". $$P(x\land y =1)~=~ P(x=1)\cdot P(y=1)$$

The probability of a union of non-disjoint events is described using the *principle of inclusion and exclusion*; sometimes called the "additive rule".

$$P(x\lor y=1)~=~P(x=1)+P(y=1)-P(x\land y=1)$$

Use the *conditional equivalence* rule of replacement to express $x\to y$ as $\lnot x\lor y$.

Comment: can you explain the solution of 5th problem?